# How to sanitize a string in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a free form string which I need to sanitize in bash in order to produce safe-and-nice filenames.

Example:

```
STAGE_NAME="Some usafe name 2/2#"
```

Expected sanitized result"

```
"some-unsafe-name-2-2"
```

Logic:

- lowercase chars
- replace all unsupported or unsafe chars with `dash` (including spaces)
- remove duplicated dashes
- remove any dashes from prefix or suffix

Use of external tools like sed is allowed as long they are portable (not using options that are no available on BSD/OSX/...).

Comment: Do you also wish to remove `STAGE_NAME=`?

Comment: First thought (untested): `STAGE_NAME=$(echo $STAGE_NAME | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sed -e 's/[^$SAFE_CHARS]/-/g' -e 's/--/-/g')` where `$SAFE_CHARS` is a string containing your definition of safe characters (otherwise all characters except '\0' and '/' are allowed, AFAIK).  What format do you expect for the 'prefix' and 'suffix'?

Comment: *grumble* (re: trying to fix the data rather than trying to fix the code that can't handle arbitrary data safely). (But don't mind me, I'm off tilting at windmills).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this pure bash function for this sanitization:

```
sanitize() {
   local s="${1?need a string}" # receive input in first argument
   s="${s//[^[:alnum:]]/-}"     # replace all non-alnum characters to -
   s="${s//+(-)/-}"             # convert multiple - to single -
   s="${s/#-}"                  # remove - from start
   s="${s/%-}"                  # remove - from end
   echo "${s,,}"                # convert to lowercase
}
```

Then call it as:

```
sanitize "///Some usafe       name  2/2##"
some-usafe-name-2-2

sanitize "Some usafe name 2/2#"
some-usafe-name-2-2
```

---

Just for an academic exercise here is an `awk` one-liner doing the same:

```
awk -F '[^[:alnum:]]+' -v OFS=- '
{
   $0 = tolower($0)
   $1 = $1
   gsub(/^-|-$/, "")
} 1'
```

Comment: That's neat :).

Comment: If you also need to shorten a string, you could add `echo "${s:0:63}"             # shorten to 64 bytes`.  Hopefully, my size calculations are correct :D