# Apostrophe in String impacting grep command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Hoping someone can help, I'm not the most experienced regarding Linux or Shell commands so hoping someone can see where I'm going wrong.

**The Scenario**

We use feature flagging in our application. When we merge pull requests into our Master branch, we wish to have a pull request gate/pipeline to ensure the developer has included the name of the feature flag in the description.

**The Solution**

To control this so we can make the gate work, we have created a pull request template that looks like this:

```
Add details here:

- [flagName='']
```

And once completed correctly by the developer it looks like this:

```
Add details here: Information for change written here.

- [flagName='flag-name']
```

In the pipeline that runs as part of the pull request gate to check the feature flag name we have this script below. Previous in the pipeline we made a call to git and assigned the pull request description to the variable $(prDesc). It should then use grep and regex to find the line in the description where the flag name is included (provided it is included by the developer) and assign it to the variable $(nameCheck). The flag name can contain any alpha, numeric or dash characters.

```
- script: |
    echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=nameCheck]$(echo $(prDesc) | grep "flagName=[a-zA-Z0-9-]\+" )'
  displayName: Flag name regex
```

If the developer hasn't included the flag name, then I would expect $(nameCheck) to be empty so we have this final script to fail the pipeline if $(nameCheck) is empty.

```
- script: |
    if [[ $(nameCheck) == '' ]]; then
      exit 1
    fi
  displayName: No flag name check
```

**The Problem**

This went through lots of testing and passed. However, once implemented we have found that if someone includes apostrophes in their pull request description e.g. so the description looks like this with "I've":

```
Add details here: I've made some changes here.

- [flagName='flag-name']
```

Then when the script (Flag name regex) with the grep command runs we now get an error because of the apostrophe.
[image]

My knowledge of shell/bash is not great so I'm struggling to see how to rectify this issue, I imagine there's a flaw in my grep/regex logic that may be causing the problem. I also assume if the developer put syntax in to cancel the apostrophe it may solve the problem but I can't realistically ask the developers to do that and the pull request description should be readable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/44810685/1216776

Comment: _variable $(nameCheck)_ : I don't know what you are doing here, but `$(nameCheck)` expands to the stdout produced by a program named `nameCheck`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get the single script to work like I was trying, so after reading the link shared by @stark I have instead opted to sanitise the pull request description before running the later scripts to check for the flag name.

Below is the code I used to sanitise the PR description, I'm replacing all ' characters with a - character.

```
- script: |
    desc=$(prDesc)
    sanitised="${desc//"'"/-}"
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sanitisedPrDesc]$sanitised"
```

Comment: Another way you might try is using the backslash (\\) to escape all the single quotes in the string of the PR description. For example, "`I\'ve made some changes here.`"

Comment: Anyway, glad that you can find a workaround to resolve the issue. Maybe, you can accept yourself answer on this case. This could be also helpful for other people who are experiencing the similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the double quotes (**`"`**) to surround the variable **`$(prDesc)`** to fix the error like as below.

```bash
echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=nameCheck]$(echo "$(prDesc)" | grep "flagName=[a-zA-Z0-9-]\+")'
```

---

**EDIT:**

Try to update your script like as below.

```bash
flagName=$(echo "$(prDesc)" | grep "flagName=[a-zA-Z0-9-]\+")
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=nameCheck]$flagName"
```

---

Comment: Thanks for the response. This makes sense but I've just tried it and I'm getting a new error now for the same script ```line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'```

Comment: Remove the strart and ending `'`. Or make them `"`.

Comment: @kuytsce, I have updated my above answer with more suggestion (see **EDIT**). Check and try it.

Comment: @BrightRan-MSFT Thanks again for the help. I've tried your edited suggestion but it's giving me the original error again ```line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''``` ```line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file``` below is the code:

flagName=$(echo "$(prDesc)" | grep "flagName=[a-zA-Z0-9-]\+")
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=nameCheck]$flagName"

Comment: @JayCravens I have also tried your suggestion of removing the outer ```'``` or replacing them with ```"``` however this didn't error but failed to create the variable so I got errors later in the pipeline